# Can't get extras from notification intent

Tags: android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, onnewintent

Can't get extras from notification intent. Read all articles here but also does not work.
Need Help. Here is my code
this is my FirebaseMessagingService. Here i add different flags, but result was the same

```kotlin
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    companion object {
        const val channel_name = "Акции"
        const val DESTINATION_PUSH_KEY = "destination"
        const val VALUE_FROM_NOTIF: Int = 1
    }


    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        super.onNewToken(token)
        getSharedPreferences("firebaseToken", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("fbToken", token)
            .putBoolean("fbTokenIsNew", true).apply();
    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)
        generateNotification(
            remoteMessage.notification?.title ?:"",
            remoteMessage.notification?.body ?:""
        )
    }

    private fun generateNotification(title: String, message: String) {
        val notifIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        val channelId = Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)
        notifIntent.putExtra(DESTINATION_PUSH_KEY, 2)
        notifIntent.putExtra("some_key", "2")
//        notifIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this,
                0,
                notifIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            )
        } else {
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, 0, notifIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            )
        }

        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, channelId)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_arus)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(longArrayOf(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000))
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        val notificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            val channelId = resources.getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)
            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(
                channelId,
                channel_name,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )
            notificationChannel.description = "Уведомления об акциях"
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(
                notificationChannel
            )
        }
        if (notificationManager.areNotificationsEnabled()) {
            notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build())
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Manifest. Also delete launchMode, and make singleTask

```xml
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
<!--            <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />-->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".push.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

And this is my MainActivity

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private var transition: Transition? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        MapKitFactory.initialize(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Utils.init(this)

//        EventBus.builder().throwSubscriberException(BuildConfig.DEBUG).installDefaultEventBus()
//        EventBus.getDefault().register(this)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            window.navigationBarColor = Color.BLACK
        }
        val builder = VmPolicy.Builder()
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build())
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_address, R.id.navigation_cabinet
            )
        )

//        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
        transition = Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM)
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            if (destination.id != R.id.navigation_home && destination.id != R.id.navigation_address
                && destination.id != R.id.navigation_promotions
                && destination.id != R.id.navigation_cabinet
            ) {
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(navView, transition)
                navView.visibility = View.GONE
            } else {
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(navView, transition)
                navView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
        this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStart()
        //called when application was closed
        intent?.let { processIntent(it) }
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStop()
    }

    override fun onRestart() {
        super.onRestart()
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStop()
    }

    fun setBottomNavigationVisibility(visibility: Int) {
        transition = Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM)
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(binding.navView, transition)
        binding.navView.visibility = visibility
    }

    fun hideKeyboardFrom(context: Context, view: View) {
        val imm = context.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        // called when application was opened
//        Log.i("intentExtras", "onNewIntent")
        intent?.let { processIntent(it) }
    }

    private fun processIntent(intent: Intent) {
        Log.i("intentExtras", "" + intent.extras?.getString("some_key"))
        Log.i("intentExtras", "" + intent.extras?.containsKey("some_key"))
        if (intent.flags != FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) {
            if (Utils.sPref.getString(Utils.PREF_SESSION_KEY, "") != "") {
                intent.extras?.getInt(MyFirebaseMessagingService.DESTINATION_PUSH_KEY)?.let {
                    Log.i(
                        "intentExtras",
                        "" + intent.extras?.getInt(MyFirebaseMessagingService.DESTINATION_PUSH_KEY)
                    )
                    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
                    navController.navigate(R.id.navigation_notifications)
                    intent.removeExtra(MyFirebaseMessagingService.DESTINATION_PUSH_KEY)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why i get null in activity. Help!)

Try all that i find there

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in notification.
Remove the notification payload from your FCM messages in order to have the data payload delivered to the onMessageReceived method.

A find an answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58542158/21806422)