# Firebase Push Notifications rrequests not Working when app is Runnig in Foreground. (App is in Java)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am New to StackOverflow, So ignore any mistake of Mine.

In my Java Application, Firebase Push Notifications working Fine When the app is in Background or the App is Closed But Not Working When the App is in Foreground.
my MyFirebaseMessagingService class code:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService
{
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"myFirebaseChannel")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        notificationManagerCompat.notify(121,builder.build());
    }
}
```

Code for My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("Weather")
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                    {
                        String msg = "Firebase Task completed";
                        if (!task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            msg = "Firebase Task Failed";
                        }
                        Log.d("Firebase", msg);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Manifest Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.firebase">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Firebase">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
                 android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Whenever i push notification request when the app is in forground , Codetrace have following logs

```
W/xample.firebas: Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(I)Z (greylist,test-api, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(ILjava/lang/String;)Z (greylist,test-api, reflection, allowed)
W/xample.firebas: Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->get(I)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->getName(I)Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Comment: Is notification not generating on foreground or click on notification is not working?

Comment: Notification not generating when the app is in foreground.

Comment: Receiving FCM notifications require the use of the internet, I worries to see in your manifest

Comment: @AjithkumarMuthukumaran But the notifications are working fine when the app is in background.  And I guess , Internet permissions are added automatically by the dependencies of android manifest.

Comment: check this out,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38451582/12709358 hope it works!

Comment: Confirm your payload. check this out, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58542019/3363789

Comment: @NikhilGupta you need to manually create notification when app is in foreground
you have created the notification ,try to put pending intent in it and put internet permission in manifest file for safe side.